# Error when using HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute more than one

Tags: asp.net

I have templates like `cart.aspx` and `mail.aspx`.I am passing them some variable and get the result view with this code

```
MySession2.Current.customer = customer;
StringWriter _writer = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("mail.aspx", _writer);
modal_info_text.InnerHtml = _writer.ToString();
```

In first line i put the variable to the session.In my `mail.aspx` file i get this variable.In other lines i get the result view of my `mail.aspx` and put it to my div.

So, there is no problem if i only use this. But i need to use an another template -`cart.aspx`-. so if i use same code for `cart.aspx` and put it to my cart div it gives an error.This is error:

`The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.`

What is the problem when i use this more than one? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A likely culprit here might be ViewState. Any change to it (adding or removing item from ViewState) in cart.aspx (or mail.aspx) might make this blow up. I guess you are trying to re-use the same template (cart and mail) for a full page view as well as injecting into another page. Better approach might be to put the re-usable components into a user control (ascx) and render it as needed.